# Database management systems_pgadmin III

Tags: database, postgresql, rdbms, pgadmin

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
pid INT NOT NULL,
pname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
price INT NOT NULL,
stock INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (pid)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer
(
Cid INT NOT NULL,
Cname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Caddress varchar(150) NOT NULL,
Ccontact varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Cid),
);

CREATE TABLE orders
(
orderid int not null,
quantity int not null,
purchased_on date not null,
totalprice float not null,
Cid INT NOT NULL,
Pid INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (orderid),
FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES Products(pid)
FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Customers(pid)
);
```

why the code is getting not able to run pgadmin III,

thanks.

Comment: You have many minor typos in your SQL statements.  But they're just that, typos. (ex: misspelled table names, wrong column names, missing commas, extra commas, etc.)  I'm sure you can figure them out.  I voted to close because questions about typos are off topic on SO, because they are not useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

All the scripts should be corrected as follows. Read the comments in front of corrected lines. All the capitalized column names and table names are placed inside double quotes.

```
CREATE TABLE "Products"
(
pid INT NOT NULL,
pname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
price INT NOT NULL,
stock INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (pid)
);

CREATE TABLE "Customer"
(
"Cid" INT NOT NULL,
"Cname" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"Caddress" varchar(150) NOT NULL,
"Ccontact" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("Cid") -- Removed additional comma (,)

CREATE TABLE orders
(
orderid int not null,
quantity int not null,
purchased_on date not null,
totalprice float not null,
"Cid" INT NOT NULL,
"Pid" INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (orderid),
FOREIGN KEY ("Pid") REFERENCES "Products"(pid), -- Added missing comma (,)
FOREIGN KEY ("Cid") REFERENCES "Customer"("Cid") -- Referenced table should be Customer not Customers and  reference key should be Cid not pid
);
```